# Matrices overwriting each other

Tags: c++, matrix, overwrite

I am trying to change (multiply by an int) the value of a certain position (i, j) in 3 different matrices depending on some condition. However, when I print the whole matrices it seems that it's multiplying the first one by all the ints (even the ones for the second and third matrices.

Here I declare the global matrices and attributes including some memory allocation:

```
int HEIGHT;
int WIDTH;
int ** matrixR= new int*[HEIGHT];
int ** matrixG= new int*[HEIGHT];
int ** matrixB= new int*[HEIGHT];
```

Then, in a function I complete the matrices:

```
for(i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++){
        matrixR[i]= new int[WIDTH];
        matrixG[i]= new int[WIDTH];
        matrixB[i]= new int[WIDTH];
}
```

Here is the conditions I evaluate for each matrix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
        float suma = pow(i - centerY, 2) + pow(j - centerX, 2);
        if (suma > pow(radius, 2)) {
            matrixR[i][j] = matrixR[i][j] * 1;
        }
    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
        float suma = pow(i - centerY, 2) + pow(j - centerX, 2);
        if (suma > pow(radius, 2)) {
            matrixG[i][j] = matrixG[i][j] * 2;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
        float suma = pow(i - centerY, 2) + pow(j - centerX, 2);
        if (suma > pow(radius, 2)) {
            matrixB[i][j] = matrixB[i][j] * 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I print the elements of the first matrix:

```
for (int k = 0; k < HEIGHT; ++k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i) {
        cout << matrixR[k][i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Where I should be getting `matrixR[i][j]*1` I'm getting `matrixB[i][j]`. Are the matrices overwriting each other? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Good written question. :)

Comment: What is the point of `matrixR[i][j] = matrixR[i][j] * 1;`?

Comment: Did you initialize the values in your matrices?

Comment: @ScottHunter it should be another number, but I'm trying to illustrate that is a different number for each matrix. So I decided to do tests with 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @S.H I fill the matrices in a loop after declaring them.

Comment: @danielsto this seems odd. Is there more code you are not showing us? And, can you show the desired output and actual output?

Comment: @MordechayS I tried not writing too much code to make it easier to answer. I think the only thing that is missing is how I fill the matrix, which is getting values from a file and translating them from hex to dec and so on...

Comment: BTW: Why aren't you using a matrix library like eigen or what you get from OpenCV? Judging based on your matrix names ("RGB"), you want to do image processing, more specifically print a filled circle in the image. That's a lot easier in e.g. OpenCV

Comment: @S.H Since it is a class asignment I am not allowed to use libraries :(

Answer (score 1):

I added values for centerX,centerY and radius and I added an initialization section (all matrix elements are one afterwards).

I can't find an error, the output is

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |


2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |


3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
```

This is the code that I've used:

```
// init variables
int HEIGHT = 5;
int WIDTH = 7;
int centerY = 3;
int centerX = 3;
int radius = 1;



int ** matrixR= new int*[HEIGHT];
int ** matrixG= new int*[HEIGHT];
int ** matrixB= new int*[HEIGHT];

for(int i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++){
        matrixR[i]= new int[WIDTH];
        matrixG[i]= new int[WIDTH];
        matrixB[i]= new int[WIDTH];
}


// init matrix values
{
for (int k = 0; k < HEIGHT; ++k)
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
        matrixR[k][i] = 1;

for (int k = 0; k < HEIGHT; ++k)
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
        matrixG[k][i] = 1;

for (int k = 0; k < HEIGHT; ++k)
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
        matrixB[k][i] = 1;
}


for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j) {
        float suma = pow(static_cast< double >(i) - centerY, 2) + pow( static_cast< double >( j ) - centerX, 2);
        if (suma > pow( static_cast< double >( radius ), 2)) {
            matrixR[i][j] = matrixR[i][j] * 1;
        }
    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
        float suma = pow( static_cast< double >( i ) - centerY, 2) + pow( static_cast< double >( j ) - centerX, 2);
        if (suma > pow( static_cast< double >( radius ), 2)) {
            matrixG[i][j] = matrixG[i][j] * 2;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
        float suma = pow( static_cast< double >( i ) - centerY, 2) + pow( static_cast< double >( j ) - centerX, 2);
        if (suma > pow( static_cast< double >( radius ), 2)) {
            matrixB[i][j] = matrixB[i][j] * 3;
        }
    }
}

for (int k = 0; k < HEIGHT; ++k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i) {
        cout << matrixR[k][i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

cout << '\n';
cout << '\n';

for (int k = 0; k < HEIGHT; ++k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i) {
        cout << matrixG[k][i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

cout << '\n';
cout << '\n';

for (int k = 0; k < HEIGHT; ++k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i) {
        cout << matrixB[k][i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

std::cin.get();
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be that it was the fact that my matrices were global. I still don't understand why it won't work, but if put (like you) in one main(), it works.

Comment: could you post your original code, where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Added this to make it compile and run:

```
for(int i=0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < WIDTH; ++j){
        matrixR[i][j] = 3;
        matrixG[i][j] = 20;
        matrixB[i][j] = 30;
    }
}

int centerX = 5;
int centerY = 5;
int radius = 2;
```

Output I get looks fine...